# Operating system data dictionary

Tags: database, unix, operating-system, dos, data-dictionary

I am starting to learn about data dictionaries and a question popped up in my head that I am unable to find the answer for online.  Do operating systems have a data dictionary?  Is there any way I could go about accessing it?

Comment: -1 for too broad, unclear, not [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question and no research effort shown

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and is suitable for `operatingsystems.stackexchange.com`!

Comment: @shekharsuman the operatingsystems private beta is going to disappear tomorrow (http://meta.operatingsystems.stackexchange.com/questions/52/shutting-down-operating-systems-stack-exchange-read-on-for-details). So the question might migrate to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ but I think the OP's intent was not to limit the question to `unix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your understanding of the term `data dictionary` is the one explained by [Wikipedia: Data Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dictionary)

> A data dictionary, or metadata repository, as defined in the IBM Dictionary of Computing, is a "centralized repository of information about data such as meaning, relationships to other data, origin, usage, and format"...

then **Yes**

[Wikipedia: Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol)

[Wikipedia: Novell - NetIQ eDirectory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetIQ_eDirectory)

[Wikipedia: Microsoft - Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory)

I'm not quite up-to-date for about 10 years, but searching for the `LDAP` term should give you good ground for further comprehension

Another very relevant (IMO) example is the

[Wikipedia: Microsoft - Windows Registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)